# Ignore a string whilst reading in a .tsv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read in a .tsv file, however I have noticed that there is a particular string within my data which is causing the following error:

> **ParserError**: Expected 112 fields in line 112, saw 115

I have traced the error to find that within my data there is `"\\t"`, which when i try reading in the file thinks its seperated by tab...

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.tsv.gz', header=None, sep='\t',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, compression='gzip', engine='python',
                 encoding='iso8859_1')
```

I have also tried to use: `sep='^\\t|\t'`.

Example data:

```
There\tShould \\t Only\tbe\t6\tcolumns\t\t
```

Output in dataframe should produce 6 columns with the string "`\\t`":

```
|There|Should \\t Only|be|6|columns|NA|
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `escapechar='\\'`to your `pd.read_csv()` arguments list?

Comment: such a simple solution I overlooked! Thankyou so much Johan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an argument to `pd.read_csv()` called `escapechar. Setting the escape char to`'\'` will solve your problem. Thus

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.tsv.gz', header=None, sep='\t', escapechar='\\',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, compression='gzip', engine='python',
                 encoding='iso8859_1')
```

does the trick, as you have shown in your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have null values and can live with reading it as a null you could use the na-values argument as part of read_csv and assign that value as N/A.

Comment: Unfortunately there are null values present in the data

Comment: You could also try setting the false_values to set that value to False when read in.

Comment: @JohanL has provided the following solution: `escapechar='\\'`, and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Aslan: Please change (or remove) your accepted answer, as it points to a non-working solution. This is confusing for someone coming to this question later. I added the working one, as reference.